# PowerPoint show

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've edited a .pps file which was made with the 2003 version and saved also as compatible with PowerPoint 97-2003 but a friend of mine can't see the last version of the file. The original file can be seen by my computer friend.

What can I do to make the new version of the .pps file to be viewable on the computer of my friend? Any tips? Where/what else do I have to check/do?

Comment: It's unclear what version you and your friend are using, can you clarify that?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see" in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell him to install [PowerPoint Viewer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=048dc840-14e1-467d-8dca-19d2a8fd7485&displaylang=en) and try again.